# javascript wont open google recaptcha

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code that counts down and the should open captcha:
And i cant find the problem!Please help!

```
    <script>
    var seconds_left = 2;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = --seconds_left;

        if (seconds_left <= 0)
        {
           document.getElementById('timer_div').innerHTML = "<div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='mykey' style='transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;'></div>";
           clearInterval(interval);
        }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
<div id="timer_div"></div>
```

Comment: What is the problem? The captcha does'n appear?

Comment: @Thanasis if i add just simple text it works just fine

Comment: How did you get the code for the div? Did you do all the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start)?

Comment: @Thanasis even captcha works itself when i echo at any place , it just not showing up if i want to use it with this javascript

Comment: Do you mind if you have jQuery?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135431/discussion-between-thanasis-and-ingus-graholskis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the reCaptcha div in the HTML from the beginning, but make it visible. Then from javascript, when 2 seconds pass, make the div visible. Like the code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="timer_div"></div>

<div id="captcha" class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='mykey' style='display:none;transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;'>
RECAPTCHA
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var seconds_left = 2;
var timerDiv = document.getElementById('timer_div');
var captcha = document.getElementById('captcha');
timerDiv.innerHTML = seconds_left;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    timerDiv.innerHTML = seconds_left;
            seconds_left--;


    if (seconds_left < 0)
    {         
        timerDiv.style.display = "none";
       captcha.style.display = "block";
       clearInterval(interval);
    }

    }, 1000);
```

You can test it in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3fty9h7/1/).

Comment: Thanks allot for this :)